# How to stop the running solr server?

Tags: apache, solr, port, server

I want to stop Solr server which is been started with below command

```
$ solr start -e dih
```

by above command my intention was to launch example DIH application bundled with the package.

Now I want to stop the above server, when I try to stop, I am getting below error:

```
$ solr stop -p 8984
```

> ERROR: Solr home directory D:\Softwares\solr-5.0.0\ must contain
>   solr.xml

I am new to Solr.

Comment: What about: `solr -stop -all`? Check: [Solr Start Script Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Start+Script+Reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had set the SOLR_HOME as solr\bin, but where as per the document , it says

> The Solr Home directory typically contains the following...
>
> - solr.xml *

so i have set SOLR_HOME to solr\server\solr, where i have solr.xml.

after modifying my home to above path, `solr stop` starts working